# Django admin model not update in admin

Tags: python, django

I use django admin to add data, i run makemigrations and migrate on my code but the Choice model won't update and i can't see the Choice model in admin.However the Question model is updated. Where is my mistake?

model.py:

```
class Choice(models.Model):
question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)

def __str__(self):
    return self.choice_text
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Register it in `admins.py` file

```
admin.site.register(Choice)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to register it in `admin.py`

```
class ChoiceAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass
admin.site.register(Choice, ChoiceAdmin)
```

Documentation for Django Admin
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/admin/